# How to dump the foreach loop output into a file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have wrote the following script to read the CSV file to perform the custom format of output.

Script is below:

```
$Content = Import-Csv Alert.csv
foreach ($Data in $Content) {
    $First = $Data.DisplayName
    $Second = $Data.ComputerName
    $Third = $Data.Description
    $Four = $Data.Name
    $Five = $Data.ModifiedBy
    $Six = $Data.State
    $Seven = $Data.Sev
    $Eight = $Data.Id
    $Nine = $Data.Time

    Write-Host "START;"
    Write-Host "my_object="`'$First`'`;
    Write-Host "my_host="`'$Second`'`;
    Write-Host "my_long_msg="`'$Third`'`;
    Write-Host "my_tool_id="`'$Four`'`;
    Write-Host "my_owner="`'$Five`'`;
    Write-Host "my_parameter="`'$Four`'`;
    Write-Host "my_parameter_value="`'$Six`'`;
    Write-Host "my_tool_sev="`'$Seven`'`;
    Write-Host "my_tool_key="`'$Eight`'`;
    Write-Host "msg="`'$Four`'`;
    Write-Host "END"
}
```

The above script executing without any error.

Tried with `Out-File` and redirection operator in PowerShell to dump the output into a file, but I'm not finding any solution.

Comment: remove the `write-host` cmdlet to pipe to `out-file`! ( or at least use `Write-Output`)

Comment: @CB is right.  `Write-Host` writes directly to the screen and not to the output stream so anything written with write-host cannot be redirected to a file.

Comment: @CB, I followed your suggestion, but still facing some issue. write-output prints extra line, which I don't want in that file. out-file option giving following error, just a sample one `Unexpected token '`'$First`'`;' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\Demo\Desktop\2parse.ps1:20 char:14
+ "mc_output= "`'$Second`'`; |out-file -filepath  "C:\Users\Demo\Desktop\dump.txt ...`

Comment: When you say that you don't want extra lines, what extra lines are you referring to? Do you want all the text on the same line? If so, if sounds as though you are trying to create something similar to a csv file and could potentially look at the `Export-Csv` cmdlet.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Write-Host` writes to the console. That output cannot be redirected unless you run the code in another process. Either remove `Write-Host` entirely or replace it with `Write-Output`, so that the messages are written to the Success output stream.

Using a `foreach` loop also requires additional measures, because that loop type doesn't support pipelining. Either run it in a subexpression:

```
(foreach ($Data in $Content) { ... }) | Out-File ...
```

or assign its output to a variable:

```
$output = foreach ($Data in $Content) { ... }
$output | Out-File ...
```

Another option would be replacing the `foreach` loop with a `ForEach-Object` loop, which supports pipelining:

```
$Content | ForEach-Object {
  $First = $_.DisplayName
  $Second = $_.ComputerName
  ...
} | Out-File ...
```

Don't use `Out-File` inside the loop, because repeatedly opening the file will perform poorly.

Comment: I would also suggest removing all backticks and moving the double quote to the end of the line. For example: `"my_object='$First';"`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician A [here string](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx) would be an even better option.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i took your `ForEach-Object` with pipeline option. it really works well :)