# Out-File inside a foreach statement

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

im trying to run this script, it works but every time that it changes from item on the list it erases the file and starts over.
what i need this to do is to get from the list of items all the users and put them all in a single text file.

```
$sitios = Get-Content -Path C:\sitios.txt
Connect-SPOService -Url https://aaa.sharepoint.com/ -Credential Admin@aaa.onmicrosoft.com
foreach ($sitio in $sitios){
$sitio
Get-SPOUser -Site $sitio -Limit ALL | Out-File -FilePath C:\usuarios.txt
}
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use the `-Append` switch of `Out-File` but all you should have to do is move it outside the loop.

```
(foreach ($sitio in $sitios){

    Write-Host $sitio
    Get-SPOUser -Site $sitio -Limit ALL 

}) | Out-File -FilePath C:\usuarios.txt
```

That way all output will be sent to `Out-File`. I added  `Write-Host $sitio` so that was not going to be in the file. You could also use `Set-Content` which is considered the preferential choice over `Out-File`

The brackets are needed around the loop so that we can use the pipe output. That `foreach` construct cannot have data directly piped from it. An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453370/how-to-dump-the-foreach-loop-output-into-a-file-in-powershell) covers the reason.

That all being said you could then do something like this

```
$sitios | ForEach-Object{
    Write-Host $_
    Get-SPOUser -Site $_ -Limit ALL 
} | Set-Content C:\usuarios.txt
```

This output should be a complex object that might not have a proper tostring equivalent. You can still get all the data with something like this instead.

```
$sitios | ForEach-Object{
    Write-Host $_
    Get-SPOUser -Site $_ -Limit ALL 
} | Export-CSV C:\usuarios.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi,i tried your suggestion but i end up with a file filled with Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPOUser

Comment: im really new to this so an apology if the fix for this is too easy or obvious

Comment: It is returning a complex object. Did the out-file solution you have do this as well (i expect it should have). I dont have the environment to test so check my update. Might need to select the column you want but at least the data should be there @rzbartali

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Add-Content Cmdlet:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156791.aspx

Instead of `Out-File` use `Add-Content`

as in:

```
[...] | Add-Content C:\usuarios.txt
```